# Add additional logic to chain of publisher transformation without affecting Publisher type

Tags: ios, swift, kotlin, swiftui, combine

Kotlin’s coroutines provide the ability to write very flat code. I am trying to work on converting some of the async iOS code to utilize Combine to flatten it out on my end as well.

**Kotlin looks like:**

```
private suspend fun getData(
        networkCall: Boolean = true,
        networkRequest: suspend () -> Either<FieldError, List<JobModel>>,
        localRequest: suspend () -> Either<FieldError, List<JobModel>>,
        cache: suspend (data: List<JobModel>) -> Unit
): Either<FieldError, List<JobModel>> {
    // getting of Jobs and passing in pair if result was from network
    var resultNetwork = false
    var result: Either<FieldError, List<JobModel>> = Left(GenericError)
    if (!networkCall) {
        result = localRequest()
    }
    // if it was not a network call and failed we will force network call
    if (networkCall || result.isLeft()) {
        resultNetwork = true
        result = networkRequest()
    }

    if (result is Either.Right && resultNetwork) {
        cache(result.b)
    }

    return result

}
```

**Swift WIP looks like:**

```
public func getData(isNetworkCall: AnyPublisher<Bool, Error>,
                    networkRequest: AnyPublisher<[Job], Error>,
                    localRequest: AnyPublisher<[Job], Error>,
                    cache: ([Job]) -> AnyPublisher<Void, Error>) -> AnyPublisher<[Job], Error>? {
    
    let getJobsRequest =  isNetworkCall.flatMap { (isCall) in
        return isCall
            ? networkRequest
            //.also { jobs in cache(jobs) }
            .catch{ _ in return localRequest }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
            : localRequest
    }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    
    return getJobsRequest
}
```

How do I add this logic of caching data as part of this AnyPublisher? I would like to have it cache in the midst of this logic transformation. Ideally there could be an *also* function that appends logic when the transaction is being completed by the subscriber.

**Solution:**

```
private func getData(isNetworkCall: AnyPublisher<Bool, Error>,
                         networkRequest: AnyPublisher<[Job], Error>,
                         localRequest: AnyPublisher<[Job], Error>,
                         cache: @escaping ([Job]) -> AnyPublisher<Void, Error>) -> AnyPublisher<[Job], Error> {
    
    // Sequence of steps for when we should do a network call
    let networkCallFlow = networkRequest
        .flatMap { jobs in // cache jobs from network
            cache(jobs)
                .replaceError(with: ()) // fire and forget cache, replace error with Void to continue
                .map { _ in jobs } // need to give back jobs to flatMap
                .setFailureType(to: Error.self) // match failure type
        }
        .catch { _ in localRequest } // return local if network fails
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    
    // Sequence of steps for when we should get from local
    let localCallFlow = localRequest
        .catch { _ in networkCallFlow } // do network flow if local call fails
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()

    return isNetworkCall
        .flatMap { $0 ? networkCallFlow : localCallFlow }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain it with `flatMap`.

It would have been easier if `cache` was also a `AnyPublisher<[Job], Error>`, then you could have had the following:

```
return isCall
    ? networkRequest
        .flatMap { jobs in cache(jobs) }
        .catch{ _ in return localRequest }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    : localRequest
```

Otherwise, you'd need to map its `Void` returned value back to `jobs`:

```
return isCall
    ? networkRequest
        .flatMap { jobs in 
            cache(jobs).map { _ in jobs }
        }
        .catch{ _ in return localRequest }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    : localRequest
```

Comment: The issue that this brings along is - what happens when ```cache()``` throws an error? - ideally it should be passing along the result of the network, but in this case it will throw whatever's in local, even if that data is outdated because cache failed. I'm looking for a way to essentially fire and forget ```cache(...)``` and always pass the result of the network if a network call was made. This will work in cases where we expect ```cache(...)``` to work as intended, but be buggy in others.

Comment: So, if you want to ignore errors thrown by `cache`, you could do something like: `cache(jobs).replaceError(with: jobs).map { _ in jobs }`

Comment: Genius! Since cache is Void, it would be 
```cache(jobs).replaceError(with: ()).map { _ in jobs } ```

I'll post the code and accept once fully tested.